# Changing colon to comma after conference address with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliography entry

```
@conference{dempsey-davis1998,
        author={Dave Dempsey and Chris Davis},
        title={Error analyses and test of pressure gradient force schemes in nonhydrostatic, mesoscale model},
        year={1998},
        pages={236--239},
        publisher=AMS,
        booktitle={12th Conf. on Numerical Weather Prediction},
        location={Phoenix, AZ}
}
```

Which, using `authoryear`, is formatted as

> Dempsey, D. and C. Davis (1998). Error analyses and test of pressure
>   gradient force schemes in nonhydrostatic, mesoscale model. In: *12th
>   Conf. on Numerical Weather Prediction*. Phoenix, AZ: Amer.
>   Meteor. Soc., pp. 236–239.

How can I change the colon that appears after the location to a comma?

Comment: what do you want to have instead the colon? please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 3):

Therefor you have to modify the existing bibmacro for this part: `publisher+location+date` in your example for the entrytype @inproceedings (=@conference).

MWE:

`refs.bib` has your bib entry as its content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%from standard.bbx
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%instead of \addcolon\space
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you want to have it exchanged in other entrytypes too, you maybe have to modify the following bibmacros as well: `institution+location+date`, `organization+location+date`.

A maybe nicer way is to use the `xpatch` package. With it you can exchange parts of macros. You just have to add it to the preamble `\usepackage{xpatch}` and then call instead of the `\renewbibmacro`:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{publisher+location+date}{\addcolon}{\addcomma}{}{}
```

It's very selfexplaining.

Comment: Note that now we have changed bot lines in the conditional to read `\setunit*{\addcomma\space}` there is no need for it in the first place. So we can dispose of the `\iflistundef{publisher}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}` in favour of the shorter `\setunit*{\addcomma\space}`.

Comment: You are right. But I leave it this way, so the reader understands how `\xpatchbibmacro` will work with this macro.